# What is the difference between settlement and colonies?

Tags: nouns

I am unsure of the difference between a settlement and a colony. I know that 'colony' means a place where people settle, but the way they run the government is tied to their original practice. But I can't understand the meaning of settlement. It seems they use the words settlement and colonies interchangeably.

Comment: It's **a colony** in the singular. A _settlement_ is a place where people settle; _colony_ usually refers to a settlement overseas where the settlers impose their own culture and forms of government on the local people.

Comment: Both words have a lot of different meanings. Look at the definitions of [colony](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/colony) and [settlement](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/settlement). Both can mean a newly-settled place, or the home of a small group of people or animals, but both also have many individual meanings. Colony sometimes but not always implies foreign rule. It might help to give a specific case where you are having trouble.

Comment: An ant-hill is a colony too

Comment: As you yourself say, *colony* implies a formal relationship with the political entity that the settlers came from; *settlement* does not imply that (but it does not rule it either). It is not unclear what further explanation you may be seeking.

Comment: I'm not sure why this deserved to be closed. "Settlement" in my opinion is often used as a more euphemistic or supportive synonym for "colony."

Comment: Why is this question closed? What details can I provide? I am a new user and am not sure why this community is so unpartable for a mistake that no one has explained to me. So nasty!

Answer (score 0):

A colony is a territory that is dependent upon, and usually governed by, a sovereign nation.

OED:
**Colony** 4.a. A settlement in a new country; a body of people who settle in a new locality, **forming a community subject to or connected with their parent state; the community so formed, consisting of the original settlers and their descendants and successors, as long as the connection with the parent state is kept up.**

A **settlement** is an area in which people live. The word is usually (but not always) used for a new area that has been recently settled. This can be anywhere.

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/settlement):
**Settlement**:

a : occupation by settlers

b : a place or region newly settled

c : a small village.